Purge queued emails from Mailjet API
Is there any way at all to purge or cleared all of the emails that have been queued to be sent from Mailjet (not mailgun)?
We've had a bad spam issue and there's thousands coming through.
Have tried deleting the sender address and the contact, nothing at all.
Mailjet's support is awful, no way to get in touch at all.
